# android downloading files

Tags: android, download

I have an application that will mail users attachments of text files. Receiving users can upload the file using this application. My question is 
1) Is download folder the default location for downloading files?
2) Is it necessary for me to provide a folder exploring options before the files can be uploaded?

Any suggestions?

Jai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)It depends on your actual call and how you are receiving the data / storing it. From what I've seen it will download to one static location however it's probably not a good idea to lean on that. There is always a possibility for that file to be moved by the user which could result in a crash or strange errors.

2)I would look into that or having the application create a temp folder to store the aforementioned text file in.

Good luck!

!k

Comment: If you are downloading from email clients how can I have the application create the temp folder, not sure I understand.

Comment: Use the default filesystem commands to create a new directory. Save all files there.

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit more? I am not sure how gmail client can store the file in the temp folder.